# Python Dicts : Needed a better output

Tags: python, dictionary, trie

guys I've written a piece of code which gives the output. Now, this is a trie. Now I want to display in a aesthetic manner. Someone help me out here . My representation should be like this [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Trie_example.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTrie_example.svg)

But what I want is how to convert this huge monster output to the neat output like this [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (3,4)] ????

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 1, 'W': 12})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 2, 'X': 25})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 3})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 4})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'S': 5})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'S': 6})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'S': 7})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'D': 8})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'D': 9})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'D': 10})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'D': 11})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'R': 16, 'E': 13, 'F': 19})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'E': 14})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'E': 15})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'R': 17})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'T': 18})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'F': 20})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'F': 21})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'D': 22})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'D': 23})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'D': 24})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'C': 26})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'C': 27})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'V': 28})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'S': 29})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
```

Comment: I got the representation part. But what I want is how to convert this huge monster output to the neat output like this [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (3,4)] ????

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should try [Pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) ! This package allow you to create some graphs line :

```
import pydot 

edges = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (3,4)] 
g = pydot.graph_from_edges(edges) 
g.write_jpeg('graph_from_edges_dot.jpg', prog='dot')
```

[image: The result]

To install it :

```
pip install pydot
```

(you can also use `easy_install` or [PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/pydot/) if you prefer)

pydot needs [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) in order to load DOT files and [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to render the graphs.

If you want to have a png picture (for example), you can replace the line

```
g.write_jpeg('graph_from_edges_dot.jpg', prog='dot')
```

by

```
g.write('graph_from_edges_dot.png', prog='dot', format='png')
```

or

```
g.write_png('graph_from_edges_dot.png', prog='dot')
```

Full documentation is available here:
[PyDot documentation](http://dkbza.org/pydot/pydot.html)

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if you have all information you wanted.